# Java object methods from ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, methods, indexing

I've searched for some answers but couldn't quite find the one I was looking for. Say if I had an ArrayList "school" and inside that ArrayList I had several "student" objects. How would I access each individual ArrayList entry to call methods on each student object?

For example, I've tried:

```
System.out.println(school[0].getStudentName());
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Inside the school ArrayList are several student objects which I created through this.

```
public void addStudent(String name, int age) {
   Student student = new Student(name, age);
   school.add(student);
}
```

Comment: by using the List function `Object get(int index)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29

Comment: Use `school.get(int i)` where `i` is the index where your `student` object is at.

Comment: You mixed up an ArrayList with an Array. Getting an array element use `arrayname[index]`. Getting an element of an array list use `arraylistname.get(index)`.

Comment: Yes, previous comments are true. I just want to add something: you wrote "I've searched for some answers but couldn't quite find the one I was looking for" while answer is in (official) Java documentation... So... Read the doc before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Java5 enhanced for loop:

```
for (Student student : school) {
    System.out.println(student.getStudentName());
}
```

Using iterators:

```
Iterator<Student> studentIterator = school.iterator();
while (studentIterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(studentIterator.next().getStudentName());
}
```

Using indexed element access (fine on ArrayList, but not necessarily on other List implementations):

```
for (int i = 0; i < school.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(school.get(i).getStudentName());
}
```

If you have an array, not an ArrayList then use array index access:

```
for (int i = 0; i < school.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(school[i].getStudentName());
}
```

Or wrap it as a list and iterate as above:

```
for (Student student : Arrays.asList(school)) {
    System.out.println(student.getStudentName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use something like this

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
public void addStudent(String name, int age) {
   Student student = new Student(name, age);
   studentList .add(student);
}
for(Student stu:studentList ){
  System.out.println("Name"+stu.name+" age"+stu.Age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot gain access to entries in an ArrayList using []. You must use the `get(int index)` method.  So, you should do this.

```
System.out.println(school.get(0).getStudentName());
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayLists don't have the bracket way of retrieving elements that arrays do. ArrayLists are a Java class (and therefore object) which has methods. Access the methods the same way you would other objects.

Try:

```
System.out.println(school.get(0).getStudentName());
```

If you want all of the students names, try the for loops expressed here in other answers.